# "Theoretical reasons" vs "theory reasons" for describing reasons which come from the theory of something

Tags: adjectives

Imagine you are studying music. The theory of music tells you that note 1 sounds good next to note 2. You want to reference this in something you are writing. As I see it, there are two ways. The first is to write, "for theoretical reasons, note 1 sounds good next to note 2." The alternative is to write "for theory reasons, note 1 sounds good next to note 2." The issue I have with the former way to write it is that it could be interpreted to mean the reasons themselves are theoretical. How to get rid of the ambiguity?

Edit: since the analogy seemed to be clouding things I will write more or less explicitly what I have in mind. I am writing a paper in mathematics. I have the following sentence I wish to communicate:

"The object is of interest, not only for reasons arising from the theory, but also for reasons arising from practical applications."

Of course I could just write the above, I know that, but I am curious about alternatives or the particular use of "theory reasons" which i think shouldn't unaccepted (although I have been sufficiently convinced it's unacceptable here).

Comment: You could use "according to music theory" or "by music theory". "Theory reasons" makes it more ambiguous.

Comment: Yes you are right, I could even say "due to reasons arising from the theory, ..." Thanks for your input. I guess theory reasons isn't acceptable in any case then?

Comment: If the work is more academic, your suggestion works. Otherwise I would use either the original "theoretical reasons" or "according to the theory...".

Comment: It is a very academic, formal work.

Comment: 'For theoretical reasons, ...' is so commonly used that it has become very woolly. If a contrast between theory and say practice is being made, it's the correct choice. But it's not a good replacement for 'according to accepted music theory, ...'. And note that in physics say, one would expect the particular theory in play to have been mentioned.

Comment: It's not a physics paper. It's a mathematics paper. I am describing something of being interest, not only for reasons arising from the theory, but also for reasons arising from practical applications.

Comment: What about 'theory-based reasons...'? 'Theory-based data analysis for social sciences' - is the title of a book that I could Google and see...

Comment: You say  **"for theoretical reasons, note 1 sounds good next to note 2."**. however I don't believe that musical theory causes the notes to sound good in combination, what it does do is give a context in which satisfying combinations can be identified.

Comment: @BoldBen It's a meaningless example. I am not writing about music, I just wanted to demonstrate the sentence structure. It's literally irrelevant what music theory actually says about notes.